# Check Passwords Match Issue (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, passwords

can anybody see the issue with the following code? My script continues, ignoring my check.

The code below is only a snippet of the code but this issue is in here somewhere after doing some debugging.

```
function validatePasswordMatch(string1, string2) {
    if (string1 != string2) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
}

var validatePasswordMatchFields = ["textbox2", "textbox3"];

if (validatePasswordMatch($("#" + validatePasswordMatchFields[0]).val(), $("#" + validatePasswordMatchFields[1]).val())) {
   (some code)
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Please change that to `return string1 == string2;`!

Comment: What does the HTML look like and do you get any errors?

Comment: Well if the `some code` runs then it means that the two values are equal. What else did you expect? Do you run it at the wrong time? What values do the two textboxes have?

Comment: alerting both strings would be a good start.

Comment: Ugh... `if (boolean) { return false; } else { return true; }`. Why do you even need this function? Just do `if (expr1 == expr2) { some code } else { return false; }`

Comment: The code continues to run when I purposely enter values that do not match. When I alert the values independently from the array it works but the check doesn't appear to be checking. My form simply submits even if I enter "return false" into either of the if's outcomes

Comment: If you’re returning `false` from the click handler of a button, use the submit handler of the form instead.

Comment: How are you triggering this function?

Comment: I'm triggering it on submit of the form. I'm going to remove the function and just use the if condition to get my result. Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>stackoverflow</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function validatePasswordMatch(string1, string2) {
      if (string1 !== string2) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    var validatePasswordMatchFields = ["textbox2", "textbox3"];
    $(document).on('click','button',function(){
      result = validatePasswordMatch($("#" + validatePasswordMatchFields[0]).val(), $("#" + validatePasswordMatchFields[1]).val())
    if (result) {
      alert("match")
    } else {
      alert("not match")
    }
    })

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="textbox2" type="text" placeholder="password">
<input id="textbox3" type="text" placeholder="password">
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button> 
</html>
```